# Pagination & get_pages?

Tags: theme-development, pagination, page-template

I have a page that list the child pages of this specifiec page but i would like to add pagination for it , how can i do this ?

here is the code that get's the pages

```
<ul id="products" class="items-thumbs">
            <?php
            $the_id = get_the_ID();

            $args = array(
            'child_of'     => $the_id,
            'title_li'     => '',
            'parent'       => $the_id,
            'sort_order'    => 'ASC',
            'sort_column'   => 'ID',
            'number'        => 20
            );

            $pages = get_pages( $args );

            $output = '';

            foreach($pages as $value){

                $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $value->ID, $attr = '' );
                $output .= "<li>";
                $output .= "<a href='" . $value->post_name . "' >" . $thumb;
                $output .= $value->post_title . "</a>";
                $output .= "</li>";
            } 

            echo $output;
            ?>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9233/how-can-i-fetch-loop-of-post-titles-via-ajax/9251#9251which is about the same question, basically querying using offset by ajax

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `query_posts()` function instead of `get_pages()`, and use a pagination plugin like wp-pagenavi. The `query_posts()` will set variables for pagination as well without any afforts.

Comment: thanks i managed to fix it using this [code](http://d.pr/blJP)